# Azure Data Factory ForEach activity pricing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having a hard time understanding how ADF will be charged in the following scenario

1 pipeline, 2 activities with 1 being a ForEach which will loop 1000+ times. Activity inside the ForEach is a stored procedure.

[image]

So will this be 2 activity runs or more than 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the result in ADF monitor - but it will be 1002 activities at $1/1000 (or whatever the current rate is).

It's much cheaper (if you mind the dollar) if you can pass the list into your proc; the lookup.output field is just json with your table list in it, which you could parse in the proc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts

Comment: thanks. I thought that would be the answer. In fact it will be closer to 15,000 loops so using the foreach activity is not the answer for me